# Why does executing a file in PySpark environment show 'No module named pyspark' despite working with 'pyspark' command in cmd?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, environment-variables

When I type pyspark it indicates the spark is working properly but when I execute the code it indicates No module named 'pyspark'
[image]
[image]
These are my environment variables
[image]
[image]

I don't understand why it is not able to detect the pyspark.

Comment: You have multiple versions of Python and/or multiple virtual environments installed on your computer.  The specific version of python you're using to run your code `c:/Users/shiva/anaconda3/envs/mytfenv/python.exe`  does not have pyspark installed.

Comment: Or, you dont have a `PYTHONPATH` env. variable configured properly.

Comment: @mazaneicha PYTHONPATH is only needed when modules are installed in nonstandard locations.  So usually that isn't the problem.

Comment: Well, its obviously a problem here.